# How do I concatenate a large Text datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the next query:

```
select 'some text: ' + cast(description as varchar(8000)) + ' end text'
From descriptionTable
```

but my description field it's larger than 8000 chars, so what can I do?, or do I have to make an application.

Thanks,

j2gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'some text: ' + cast(description as varchar(max)) + ' end text'
From descriptionTable
```

Because

```
declare @description varchar(8000) = REPLICATE('a', 8000)
select datalength('some text: ' + @description + ' end text')
select datalength('some text: ' + cast(@description as varchar(max) ) + ' end text')
```

Returns 8000 and 8020 respectively. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Michael, for the varchar(max).

Answer (score 1):

When the the length is specified in declaring a VARCHAR variable or column, the maximum length allowed is still 8000.  If the length is greater than 8000, you have to use the  MAX specifier as the length.

Varchar(8000) stores a maximum of 8000 characters. Varchar(max) stores a maximum of 2 147 483 647 characters

[Here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2005/..%5Cfaq%5Csql-server-2005-varchar-max-p01.aspx)  you can find many answers regarding varchar size issues

so use max like this..

```
  select 'some text: ' + cast(description as varchar(max)) + ' end text'
  From descriptionTable
```